# perl regex to match with a string with a '+' character

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $line = "buildroot+platfs2g@final.x86_64";
my $regex = "buildroot+platfs2g@final.x86_64";

if ($line =~ m/^$regex$/) {
    print "matched\n";
} else {
    print "not matched\n";
}
```

Even though `$line` and `$regex` are the same string, regex is not matched.
If I remove `+` from both of the strings, they match.
How do I get those two strings to match with `+` in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `+` is a metacharacter in regex.

Your pattern is therefore "reading" `t+` as "one or more instances of 't'" not literally like you want.

There's two solutions:

- `quotemeta` on your string will escape any metachars (`+`) `my $regex = quotemeta "buildroot+platfs2g@final.x86_64";`
- `\Q` and `\E` to quote your regex. `if ($line =~ m/^\Q$regex\E$/) {`
- And as Borodin notes - you don't actually need a regex at all here. `if ( $line eq $regex ) {` will do the trick. (but rename `$regex` because it will confuse people).

Comment: It looks like single quotes and `eq` are the best choice here.

Comment: ty very much. it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems here.

You can solve the problem you have noticed by escaping the `+` in your regex - as is it a metacharacter and has a special meaning in regexes. There are a few ways to escape a metacharacter - the simplest is to put a `\` in front of it.

You also have a `.` in your regex. That's another metacharacter. You will need to escape that too.

Then there's the fact that your strings don't contain what you think they contain. Variables are expanded in double-quoted strings, so when Perl sees `@final` in a double-quoted string, it looks for an array with that name to insert at that point. This code wouldn't have compiled with `use strict` turned on. You can escape the `@` in the same way, but it probably makes more sense to just change your double-quoted strings to single-quoted ones (as variables aren't expanded in single-quoted strings).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always use these.
use strict;
use warnings;

# Single-quote strings that don't need double-quotes
my $line = 'buildroot+platfs2g@final.x86_64';
# Escape metacharacters in regexes
my $regex = 'buildroot\+platfs2g@final\.x86_64';

if ($line =~ m/^$regex$/) {
    print "matched\n";
} else {
    print "not matched\n";
}
```

Of course, if you're matching two strings that should be exactly the same, then regexes are the wrong tool. Better to just use `eq`.